# How can I pass a parameter to PDF rendering in ActiveReports 14?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, activereports

I am implementing a .Net Core 3.1 REST API that needs to generate a PDF file for a given contract (the contract ID is known).

I have adopted the following code in [ActiveReports 14 documentation](https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsnet/docs/v14/online/rendering-to-pdf.html) to generate a sample report without any dynamic data in the API, and it is working fine:

```cs
// Provide the page report you want to render.
System.IO.FileInfo rptPath = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"..\..\PageReport1.rdlx");
GrapeCity.ActiveReports.PageReport pageReport = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.PageReport(rptPath);

// Create an output directory.
System.IO.DirectoryInfo outputDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyPDF");
outputDirectory.Create();

// Provide settings for your rendering output.
GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Page.Settings pdfSetting = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Page.Settings();

// Set the rendering extension and render the report.
GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Page.PdfRenderingExtension pdfRenderingExtension = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Page.PdfRenderingExtension();
GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Rendering.IO.FileStreamProvider outputProvider = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Rendering.IO.FileStreamProvider(outputDirectory, 
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(outputDirectory.Name));
            
// Overwrite output file if it already exists
outputProvider.OverwriteOutputFile = true;

pageReport.Document.Render(pdfRenderingExtension, outputProvider, pdfSetting);
```

However, now I need to modify the report to contain the dynamic data. The dynamic data is selected based on the contract ID. I think I can manage to create the necessary data source(s) (SQL) and dataset(s), but first I need to figure it out, how the contract ID should be passed for data sources/datasets to return the correct data.

Any advice?

Comment: Any solution for this I'm facing same issue but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters from Active reports designer and set their properties according to your requirement. It will fetch data on the base of parameters passed.